# Converting multiple rows into one row different columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am down to any help with converting multiple rows into multiple columns in Excel. I need to change table like this:

[image: this].

Into something like this:

[image: this].

I've tried coding it in VBA, because transpose function does not work exactly like this, but I don't know how to loop it with detecting code from left column 1st table. I've read something about doing similar things in T-SQL but I have no clue how to code in this language. I'm up to any ideas about function I should use or anything. Btw. I need it for many ID's not only short table like in example.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) and a series of [Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

We can put the column A values as the keys of the Dictionary and create a collection to hold all of the column B values for each key. Then you can output the gathered values from the dictionary keys & collections back into the sheet.

```vb
Sub Example()

    Const STARTING_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const STARTING_ROW As Long = 1

    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Getting the last row from column A
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, STARTING_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Looping through every row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = STARTING_ROW To lastrow
        Dim ValA As String, ValB As String
        ValA = Cells(i, STARTING_COLUMN).Value
        ValB = Cells(i, STARTING_COLUMN + 1).Value
        
        'If Column A is not blank
        If ValA <> "" Then
            'Add new ColA values to the dictionary
            'Saving the ColA value as the dictionary key and a collection as the dictionary item
            If Not dic.exists(ValA) Then dic.Add ValA, New Collection
            
            'Add the ColB value to a collection based on its ColA value
            dic(ValA).Add ValB
        End If
    Next
    
    'Clear the table
    Cells(STARTING_ROW, STARTING_COLUMN).Resize(lastrow, 2).ClearContents
    
    'For each collection in the dictionary
    For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1
        'Put the dictionary key in column A
        Cells(STARTING_ROW + i, STARTING_COLUMN) = dic.keys()(i)
        
        'For each item in the collection
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To dic.items()(i).Count
            'Put the collection items in the row
            Cells(STARTING_ROW + i, STARTING_COLUMN + j) = dic.items()(i)(j)
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

If your data starts from a cell other than A1, change the `STARTING_ROW` & `STARTING_COLUMN` to the appropriate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an up-to-date version of Excel, you can use a combination of the UNIQUE, FILTER and TRANSPOSE functions to achieve the result without resorting to VBA.

[image]

First put the formula in D1 to extract all the unique Ids from Column A.
`=UNIQUE(A1:A9)`.

Then use these values as the input to create the other columns, by using the formula in cell E1 as `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B$1:B$9,A$1:A$9=D1))`, and filling the formula down.

[image]

Comment: Wow, those are cool functions. Which version of Excel do I need to be able to have them?

Comment: @Toddleson They are in the current channel if you have a 365 subscription.